# Tracing saved files

Tags: encryption

Suppose I create a word or a PDF document on my home computer. I then save this file to a location on my computer hard drive and email it to a friend as an attachment over gmail.
My friend downloads this file onto their computer and uploads it to a company website.
Can the company see my name and computer ID in the file properties, even though I emailed the file to my friend and they uploaded from their computer (not mine)?
Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://scienceblogs.de/klausis-krypto-kolumne/2017/06/06/the-yellow-dot-code-that-led-to-arrest-of-whistleblower-reality-winner/  Which is to say, it varies wildly depending on your choice of technologies.

Comment: yes, there's a ton of meta info in both word docs and PDFs. a text file would be far more private.